# Doctrine ODM, MongoDB, Symfony2 - Inserting a document creates two database entries, should create one

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm new to Symfony 2 with Mongo (I've used Symfony before and I used MongoDB before, just not them together).

I have this code in Symfony 2:

```
$dm = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb');
$manager = $dm->getManager();
$pain = new Pain();
$pain->setScale(5);
$pain->setDateStart(new \DateTime());    
$manager->persist($pain);
$manager->flush();
```

Pretty basic Symfony stuff. But running this code once creates two database entries like this:

```
> db.Resources.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5276842640b59ece04000000"), "scale" : 5, "dateStart" : ISODate("2013-11-03T17:13:10Z"), "type" : "pain" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5276842740b59ecd04000004"), "scale" : 5, "dateStart" : ISODate("2013-11-03T17:13:11Z"), "type" : "pain" }
```

Here is my config.yml:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: mongodb://localhost:27017
        options: {}
default_database: znmj
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

And here's the Pain class:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="Resources")
 */
class Pain
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
 */
protected $id;  

/**
 * @var integer
 * @MongoDB\Int
 */
protected $scale;

    // getters and setters below
}
```

I really can't figure out how to handle this issue or debug it. I can get 0 or 2 entries in the database.
I Googled a lot for this, and couldn't find anything even remotely related.

Any ideas on what may be causing the problem?

UPDATE:
And of course the culprit was
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">`
This is a great lesson in debugging.

Comment: the fact that there are two distinct dateStart values tells me your symfony code ran twice.

Comment: the code is correct. As @muratgu say, maybe you are calling the controller/library twice.

Comment: @muratgu I've checked that, nope. The controller is running once. The <>1s difference is weird (as it's always around that) but I still can't pinpoint the problem - why there's 2 same documents there.

Comment: please add a 10 sec delay before the line calling `persist` and tell us what the new `dateStart` values are.

Comment: @muratgu thanks for your help :-) It looks like mine "testing if it's running twice" was flawed. After looking into that more, and debugging whole day.. the culprit was:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">` in layout.html.twig
The "best" thing is that it wasn't showing on the FireBug.
So lesson for future once again.
Sorry for wasting your time guys.